# WCF MaxPendingAccepts: Default value 0

Tags: wcf, self-hosting

According to MSDN, if MaxPendingAccepts for a WCF-Service is set to 0, WCF will configure the value for us.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.channels.httptransportbindingelement.maxpendingaccepts(v=vs.110).aspx

What does that mean? Is it dynamically changed? What is the algorithm behind that?

Comment: The documentation states "The default value of MaxPendingAccepts is 0".  Default value means just that - if you don't supply a value, the framework will set it for you.  0 in this case.  If you set it to 0, it will be 0.

Comment: no, documentation states:
"The default value of MaxPendingAccepts is 0, which means WCF will configure the value for you."
So that sounds to me, if you do not set it or set it to 0, a good value will be chosen by WCF.

Comment: I agree that it could have been said better, but I also believe that the proper interpretation of that sentence is that if you don't not set it, 0 will be the value chosen by the framework.

Comment: ok that's clear. But my question is, what value will the system chose if it is set to 0?

Comment: 0.  If you don't give a value, it will be 0.  If you set it to 0, it will be 0.

Comment: Think of the various (and many) configuration options required by WCF.  They have default values developer's don't have to set every single one - they only need to set the ones where the default value is not suitable for their needs.  For example, say there's a clothing store that sells T-Shirts, and the default color is black.  If you say "Give me a T-Shirt", you'll get a black one.  If you say "Give me a black T-Shirt", you'll still get a black one.  If you say "Give me a red T-Shirt", you'll get a red T-Shirt.

Comment: Nope, thats just wrong. If you set it to 0, or you don't set it at all...the system will choose a good value for you!!!
Thats what this sentence means at all, and that's a standard approach in software development.
There is a special value, in this case 0, which means you do not want to tell the system an exact value, the system will choose a 'good' value for you.

Comment: You're entitled to your interpretation, but I believe you are completely off the mark on your reading.  It doesn't make sense and it's completely contrary to the way every other configuration option works.  It simply does not make sense - how is the system going to know what is the best value for your scenario?  Try it out and see what happens - don't set it, then try setting it to 0 and then try setting it to some other value.

Comment: Sometimes systems choose a good value for you (how it is estimated does not matter for now) and sometimes you want to configure an exact value. So how do you tell a system, if there is just one configuration value that you can change!?
This is done by a special value, in this case 0, that just means, system please choose a value for me! For example dependent on the machine setup!
That's how configurations work in many cases. And only in this context the sentence makes sense:
 "The default value of MaxPendingAccepts is 0, which means WCF will configure the value for you."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I took a look at the source code for [`System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpTransportBindingElement`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.ServiceModel/System/ServiceModel/Channels/HttpTransportBindingElement.cs,e174f365021edaef).  The default constructor for the class has the following line of code:

```
this.maxPendingAccepts = HttpTransportDefaults.DefaultMaxPendingAccepts;
```

Taking a look at [`HttpTransportsDefault`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.ServiceModel/System/ServiceModel/Channels/TransportDefaults.cs,5ab00e7b7eeaa017) shows the following code:

```
// We use 0 as the default value of the MaxPendingAccepts property on HttpTransportBindingElement. In 4.5 we always
// use 10 under the hood if the default value is picked. In future releases, we could adjust the underlying default
// value when we have the dynamic expending pattern of BeginGetContext call implemented and the heap fragmentation issue
// from NCL layer solved.
const int PendingAcceptsConstant = 10;
internal const int DefaultMaxPendingAccepts = 0;
internal const int MaxPendingAcceptsUpperLimit = 100000;
internal static int GetEffectiveMaxPendingAccepts(int maxPendingAccepts)
{
    return maxPendingAccepts == HttpTransportDefaults.DefaultMaxPendingAccepts ?
                                PendingAcceptsConstant :
                                maxPendingAccepts;
}
```

So it looks like if you use 0 (the default) you will actually get 10, and you have an upper limit of 100,000.

So in essence if you set the value to 0 (or don't even set it all, which will cause it to default to 0) the actual value will be 10.

Comment: @user1682946 - You're welcome.  I got to learn something new as well, so it was a win-win.